# Magento set customer my account layout to one column

Tags: xml, magento, layout, account

I am currently using the latest version of Magento 1.7.0.2. After a customer logs on they are presented with the typical 2 column my account details with the navigation menu in the left hand position. I need to have this navigation deleted so that my dashboard page becomes only one column. I also don't want the empty space of the left navigation after it's deleted. I have tried the  thing in local.xml but what happens is that the navigation menu in the customer my account is removed BUT also any page with a left sidebar loses that sidebar as well.
Please not that I'm running a custom template and the only customer.xml file is in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout. My local.xml is in /app/design/frontend/default/custom_template/layout.

How would I be able to do this and what is the path for the files I need to edit. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code for the customer my account layout in the customer.xml

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
    <!--remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/-->
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>

    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you want One column layout for Dashboard Page only, so Make your changes in 
 `customer_account_index` Layout handle as this is for Customer account dashboard layout.

And if you will make your changes on `customer_account` handle it will apply on all the customer pages if not updated on particular handle.

Hope this Help !!