# Magento SIngle Column Layout for Customer Account Dashboard

Tags: magento

I am trying to convert the 2 column layout of my account pages in Magento to a 1 column layout. I do not have any need to the navigation links on the left column. I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 and have very limited programming experience.

I have been told by the theme developer that I need to customize my local.xml file.

I have also found another thread on this site - [Magento set customer my account layout to one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890332/magento-set-customer-my-account-layout-to-one-column) which suggests I should be looking at the `<customer_account>` handle.

Is anyone able to tell me what changes I need to make to to this file? Below is what I believe to be the relevant section of the local.xml file.

Thanks!

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>reorder</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>

<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log Out</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
            <title>Log Out</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
            <liParams/>
            <aParams>class="top-link-logout"</aParams>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="sales/reorder_sidebar" name="sale.reorder.sidebar" as="reorder" template="sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>

<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log In</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
            <title>Log In</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
            <liParams/>
            <aParams>class="top-link-login"</aParams>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>

<customer_account_edit translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your local.xml file as follows.

```
<customer_account_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard_hello" name="customer_account_dashboard_hello" as="hello" template="customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" />
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard_address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml"/></block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Change is

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately my local.xml file does not have the above code. I also do not have the  'customer_account_index' handle. Should I be adding the action method to any of the code listed in my first post or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Yes. You should add this handle in your xml file if it is not available.

Comment: I have just added all of the code above into my local.xml. It has changed to 1 column layout as desired but now how of have the dashboard content listed twice on the page. I also want to change all of the other related customer pages to 1 column layout, can this all be changed from the 1 handle?